# TypeScript datatype reflection: is there a 'DataType' class?

Tags: typescript, reflection, types

I'm not sure whether classes are objects in TypeScript.

But would it be possible to code something like this? I couldn't find anything about it, so i'm assuming it's not possible, but still asking to make sure.

```
public datatype : DataType = String;
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But it should be `public datatype : StringConstructor = String;`. Everything in javascript is an object.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Maybe I wasn't clear, but I meant that that variable should hold a datatype, so it could be assigned "String, Object, number, Array" etc. Would that work?

Comment: `String`, `Object`, `Number`, `Array`, `Function` are all objects in js (or functions, which are objects as well). Just type "Number" in your browser console and see what happens. In typescript they have corrosponding types: `StringConstructor`, `ObjectConstructor`, `NumberConstructor`, `ArrayConstructor`, `FunctionConstructor` (which can be found in the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts)). Have you tried anything? What is the problem?